# ASP.NET website consuming WCF service error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I get the following error on my asp.net website, while trying to invoke a wcf service method:

> *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not* 
>   *properly respond after a period of time, or established connection* 
>   *failed because connected host has failed to respond 77.XXX.XX.XX:809*

And then more in detail, I get a socketexception, webexception and also this endpointnotfoundexception:

> *There was no endpoint listening at* 
>   *http://77.XXX.XX.XX:809/RemoteSyncService/ that could accept the* 
>   *message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.*

---

The wcf service (RemoteSyncService) is hosted in a .net application on the 77.XXX.XX.XX server. The binding used is basicHttpBinding.

The endpoint address, used in the asp.net site web.config is:

```
http://77.XXX.XX.XXX:809/RemoteSyncService 
// this is the same on the remote server
```

The service code for the asp.net website was automatically generated, by using the 'add service reference' feature in VS2010 (on this address: http://77.XXX.XX.XXX:809/RemoteSyncService/mexHttp, as described in the other remote server).

All works perfectly on the dev machine..

What I tried and works:

- running/debugging the asp.net locally, and invoking methods
- trying to contact the wcf service with wcf test client
- the asp.net site can contact the other server, because a ftp transfer from my asp.net site to the remote server was successful
- pinging the remote server

*Will provide code if needed..*

Comment: port 809 is probably blocked.

Comment: Are you sure you need to put a "/" at the end of "http://77.XXX.XX.XX:809/RemoteSyncService/" ?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your production server isn't firewalling you.